# How can I hide winform controls from second monitor?

Tags: c#, winforms, monitor

I have my winform app displayed simultaneously on dual screens: one on my laptop, one on my tv (connected via cable).
My app has a listview and a richtextbox. By default, the whole app displays on my laptop's screen, and it's ok. The problem is, how can I display only the richtextbox on my tv's screen , not the listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. It uses the [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) collection, each index is one of  your [monitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx). Check if the location of your application is on your TV and write the appropiate code to hide what you need to. You could put this in the [LocationChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged.aspx).

```
if(Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Contains(this.Bounds))  // 0 is the primary monitor
{                                                      // use the index that equates to your TV
    // Hide your listbox here.
}
```